# How do i suppress the prompt in shell scripting/sql

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql, oracle11g

Below is the code used in my shell script octane.sh:

```
  value=$(<max.txt)
    echo "$value"
    fldr=`date +%d%b%Y`
    SCRIPT_HOME=/oradata/ora_backup/report/summary/OCTANE/
    $SQLPLUS -s $USER/$PASSWD@$ORACLE_SID  @/oradata/ora_backup/report/summary/OCTANE/octane.sql $value
```

I am using SET VERIFY OFF in octane.sql

```
    set serveroutput on;
    set heading off;
    set echo off;
    set feedback off;
    set linesize 1000;
    SET VERIFY OFF;
    spool /oradata/ora_backup/report/summary/OCTANE/birlasm.sql
    set serveroutput on
    DECLARE
    sqltxt VARCHAR2(3000);
    IDS number := &1;
    part VARCHAR2(100);
    bill VARCHAR2(300);
    TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
........
```

It is working fine if i run the shell script as nohup./octane.sh &

But it is giving below if i schedule the cron job.

```
Enter value for 1: 
SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.
```

Please suggest

Comment: Add `set define off;` along with other set statements.

Answer (score 2):

Add set define off as follows:

```
set serveroutput on;
set heading off;
set echo off;
set feedback off;
set linesize 1000;
SET VERIFY OFF;
set define off;
spool /oradata/ora_backup/report/summary/OCTANE/birlasm.sql
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    sqltxt VARCHAR2(3000);
    IDS number := &1;
    part VARCHAR2(100);
    bill VARCHAR2(300);
    TYPE cur IS REF CURSOR;
........
```